# DirectX9 CreateOffscreenPlainSurface returns D3DERR_INVALIDCALL

Tags: c++, directx-9

Using c++ in Visual Studio 2017 community edition. The relevant code as far as I can see:

```
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 surface = NULL;...

...//create surface
HRESULT result = d3ddev->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
    100,
    100,
    D3DFMT_X8B8G8R8,
    D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
    &surface,
    NULL);

if (result == D3DERR_INVALIDCALL) 
{
    MessageBox(window, "Error creating surface", "Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
```

It builds with no issue, but when debug/running I get the messagebox error. I assume I'm messing something up with the variable "surface" but I can't see where. Also, if I change the pool from default to scratch it no longer returns the invalid call, but I can't utilize the surface in later code.

Thanks for your time and any help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong surface format, confusing the incorrect D3DFMT_X8B8G8R8 with the correct D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8.

Comment: Technically in Direct3D 9 you can't assume any format is supported for ``D3DPOOL_DEFAULT`` and have to explicitly check for support with ``IDirect3D9::CheckDeviceFormat``. You then have to have fallback logic to deal with missing format support. This was the main motivation behind the [Direct3D Hardware Feature Level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) design for DirectX 10+. Speaking of which, you should be using DirectX 11 instead of legacy Direct3D 9.